# multiplication of polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$

Tags: proof-verification, polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p(x) = 1 + x + x^2$ and $q(x) = 1 + x + x^3$. Then is the multiplication $p(x)q(x)$ obtained like this:

$$p(x)q(x)= (1 + x + x^2)(1 + x + x^3) = 1 +x +x^3 + x + x^2 + x^4 + x^2 + x^3 + x^5 $$
$$= 1 + x^4 + x^5?$$

Comment: That is correct, but what has this to do with `irreducible-polynomials`?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos nothing, just that they are irreducible